# RDP Alternative on linux (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

Does someone know a valid alternative on Linux that runs with performance comparable to the RDP on windows 10?

FreeRDP and VNC have bad FPS performance, and the only program I found which can decently manage the remote connection is NoMachine, but it's still far from the RDP experience on Windows 10.

Update: I've already tried `xrdp`, but it has the same performance of VNC.

More details:

- Yes, I'm in control of my server and I can reach it via VPN or external internet.
- **The client is windows and the server is Linux.**
- "Bad performance" means that every action is not fluid and responsive like when I'm connected to a windows server via RDP
- I want to use a normal program like Visual Studio Code for programming, normal browser for surfing, and yes some time watch videos and not much else.
- This server does not have a GPU.

Comment: welcome to SU, you want RDP-like as client (using it from linux to access windows) or as a server (using rdp client to access linux) ?

Comment: Are you in control of the server? Are both server & client on Linux?

Comment: "Bad FPS performance" isn't very descriptive - what kind of programs do you want to run? If you run OpenGL programs where screen content changes quickly, all image- or delta-based methods will have "bad FPS performance". In that case, have a look at [VirtualGL](https://www.virtualgl.org/), which uses hardware acceleration on the remote machine.

Comment: I've updated the question with, I hope, all the answers to your questions.

Comment: xrdp has considerably faster performance than vnc. However, it does not have the performance you would get in a single computer. What I use is xming on the Windows computer with unencrypted, plain TCP connections over the LAN. I do not use X forwarding over SSH, and eliminating the compression and encryption overhead result in an improvement. Start xming on your Windows computer with `start "Xming" /D "c:\program files (x86)\xming\" /b "xming.exe" :0 -ac -from 0.0.0.0 +bs -clipboard -multiwindow -nowinkill` and then connect from the LInux computer with `DISPLAY=x.x.x.x:0.0 command`.

Answer (score 8):

Windows RDP achieves its speed by the fact that both server and client are created
by Microsoft, which allows it to be heavily optimized.

For example: RDP uses compression to speed up the screen casting,
and especially video codecs.
To support larger screens than full HD, it will use the
AVC/H.264 video codec. This allows it to use the video GPU
to speed up the video display and make it more fluid, but it will fall back
to the CPU if it is not available.

NoMachine is similarly using a fast protocol, the NX protocol, to achieve its
speed, but it cannot compete with Microsoft's RDP.

I would therefore look for products that have both server and client components
and that use a non-VNC protocol. Below are some such products that you may
try:

- [**Xpra**](https://xpra.org)
  An open-source multi-platform persistent remote display server and client for forwarding applications and desktop screens. Among its
  [Wiki](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/tree/master/docs/Usage#other-documentation-links)
  is listed OpenGL client-side "for better window rendering performance" and server-side for "running accelerated OpenGL application",
  so it may be fast enough.
- [**Apache Guacamole**](http://guacamole.apache.org/)
  A clientless remote desktop gateway whose viewer is any browser that supports HTML5. It supports standard protocols like VNC, RDP, and SSH.
  As it supports the RDP protocol it might be fast enough, although the
  documentation does not mention which version of RDP.
  [Setup documentation](https://www.tecmint.com/guacamole-access-remote-linux-windows-machines-via-web-browser/)
- [**TeamViewer**](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/)
  Perhaps the best-known remote screen product, cross-platform but not open-source.
  I have used it many times, and it always was very responsive and feature-rich.

Comment: How many of these have you tried, and how do they compare? Guacamole is essentially a web client/front end for many other protocols.

Answer (score 2):

I will say you use rdesktop command but it seems that this project will not have a mantainer. Very light software to connect via RDP over Linux shell.

I suggest you use **Remmina** if rdesktop cannot be find at Ubuntu 18, give a try:

I have used these two ones at work when I have to access Windows Servers at my Ubuntu desktop and I always have a good impression of rdesktop a free reverse engineering of RDP protocol. At this link bellow you can find reference for this.

Comment: Apart from the fact that they are both great applications, they are just clients. And a client is not really what's making a difference in a remote connection performance because it depends on the protocol you are using. I've updated the question with more detail of what i'm asking.

Comment: +1 Remmina is my favorite!

Comment: @Nuked I have update my reply to consider the fact that rdesktop is a free RDP reverse engineering tool.

Comment: Yes, but my client is Windows and my server is Linux so this solution is not applicable to my situation.

Comment: Updated: Sorry, looking at 1st time your question was not so clear for me. You should say at 1st post that you are connecting to a Ubuntu Server from Windows 10 by RDP. @Nuked

Comment: But it was in the 1st post!  Now I've made it Bold so it's more visible

Comment: Ok, I will add a upvote, but I got a downvote just for nothing... Trying to help. For me don't mind if one machine is server or not...Just to be clear you should say at 1st message, which OS you should connect with another one. Fixed my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well since this is from January, i found this trying to use RDP on a far away server on AWS on linux.

xRDP works great on LAN scenarios per example even on WAN, but if u have a server that its very far away with high latency as expected, it fails, i tried to tweak xRDP without any improvement, as it states here its slow compared to Windows RDP, even on same latency and on same machine.

I tried VNC it was same slow.

First i thought it was something related from GNOME, LXDE, LXQT, XFCE well using xRDP it was faster on those light desktops, but again its not that responsive as you expect from windows side.

What u needed is X2GO that should do it i read about this here: https://hasanyavuz.ozderya.net/?p=503

here it states why RDP from Windows its better than linux counterparts, but also there are some alternatives to achieve that smooth/feeling from windows RDP on linux, what u need its something using NX protocol, like Nomachine,Xpra and i found X2GO also use this.

it seems Xpra its a much better solution but since i couldnt move forward adding the PPK to the Xpra interface (Since EC2 servers on AWS uses this) and X2GO was so easy to use, just install and works, well X2GO its the winner for me

Answer (score 1):

You could try `xrdp` with `tigervnc-server`, but you will need to adjust screen resolution, etc. to suit your needs.  I can't take credit for this suggestion because I found it on [It'zGeek](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html).

Comment: Sorry i didn't write it in the question but i've already tried it and the performance is the same of vnc.

Answer (score 1):

An open-source alternative to RDP on linux, which is comparable to Teamviewer  (but still in development) is rustdesk (rustdesk.com)

The usability is like Teamviewer with comparable performace.
It is not like RDP on windows, but there seems to be nothing alike in terms of performance and integration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Marlon may be correct ... the issue may be on the server side. Perhaps you are limited by your hardware, as in some systems are assisted by use of the GPU for hardware acceleration (on the server). If you figure it out, please let us know so that we can benefit too.